# How to use a for-loop to create a new variable based on differences between posixct for log files

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, posixct

I am trying to loop through a log file dataset I have, to add a variable in which a server session number is stored for every observation. For the first line, I want to create a new variable 'session number' with value 1. After that, I want a different session number for the following line if the 'ResearchNumber' differs from the line before. If it is the same 'ResearchNumber', I want to check whether the difference in the Posixct variable is larger than 18000 seconds (or 30 minutes). If that's the case, I want to create a different session number (by increasing this with 1). In all the other cases, I want the session number to be the same as the previous line. To summarize, I want to create session numbers based on inactivity for longer than 30 minutes per participant.

I have tried several things, but my code doesn't seem to loop over all the lines, and with other solutions the time difference doesn't calculate in the right way.

I hope someone can help me fix this problem. All help is appreciated!

```py
# create example data

ResearchNumber <- c("AL001","AL002","AL003")

DateTimeTag <- c(
  as.POSIXct('2014-09-29 10:35:40', tz='GMT'),
  as.POSIXct('2014-09-29 10:35:42', tz='GMT'),
  as.POSIXct('2014-09-29 10:38:18', tz='GMT')
)

logdata <- data.frame(ResearchNumber, DateTimeTag)


# loop through logdata to add variable to every observation with a server session number

linecount <- 1
for (lines in logdata) {
  if (linecount == 1) {
    session_number <- 1
    logdata$session_number <- session_number
    datetime <- logdata$DateTimeTag
    participantbefore <- logdata$ResearchNumber
    linecount <- (linecount + 1)
  } 
  else if (linecount > 1) {
    difference <- (logdata$DateTimeTag - datetime)
    if (logdata$ResearchNumber != participantbefore) {
      logdata$session_number <- (session_number + 1)
      participantbefore <- logdata$ResearchNumber
      session_number <- (session_number + 1)
      datetime <- logdata$DateTimeTag
    }
    else if (difference > 18000) {
      logdata$session_number <- (session_number + 1)
      participantbefore <- logdata$ResearchNumber
      session_number <- (session_number + 1)
      datetime <- logdata$DateTimeTag
    }
    else {
      logdata$session_number <- (session_number)
      participantbefore <- logdata$ResearchNumber
      datetime <- logdata$DateTimeTag
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You beat me @docendo discimus!

Here's a dplyr solution.

```
library(tidyverse) # brings in dplyr library

# make better example data
ResearchNumber <- c("AL001","AL002","AL003", "AL003", "AL003")

DateTimeTag <- c(
  as.POSIXct('2014-09-29 10:35:40', tz='GMT'),
  as.POSIXct('2014-09-29 10:35:42', tz='GMT'),
  as.POSIXct('2014-09-29 10:38:18', tz='GMT'),
  as.POSIXct('2014-09-29 12:00:00', tz='GMT'),
  as.POSIXct('2014-09-29 12:15:18', tz='GMT')
)

logdata <- data.frame(ResearchNumber, DateTimeTag)

logdata

logdata <- logdata %>% 
  arrange(ResearchNumber) %>% 
  group_by(ResearchNumber) %>% 
  mutate(difftime = difftime(DateTimeTag, lag(DateTimeTag), units = "mins"),
         DiffSess = case_when(
           is.na(difftime) ~ TRUE,
           difftime > 30 ~ TRUE,
           TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(session_number = cumsum(DiffSess))
```

The result

```
  ResearchNumber DateTimeTag         session_number difftime  DiffSess
  <fct>          <dttm>                       <int> <drtn>    <lgl>   
1 AL001          2014-09-29 10:35:40              1   NA mins TRUE    
2 AL002          2014-09-29 10:35:42              2   NA mins TRUE    
3 AL003          2014-09-29 10:38:18              3   NA mins TRUE    
4 AL003          2014-09-29 12:00:00              4 81.7 mins TRUE    
5 AL003          2014-09-29 12:15:18              4 15.3 mins FALSE
```